# Is there a 2 Value Look up function in MS Excel that can perform the following?

Tags: excel, match, formula

I am going crazy over this. It seems so simple yet I can't figure this out. I have two worksheets. First worksheet is my data. Second is like an answer key. Upon checking checking, A1:B1 in Sheet 1 is a match with the conditions in Row 52 in SHEET 2, therefore, the value in Column C is "MGC". What is the formula that will perform this function? It's really hard to explain without the data so I pasted a link of the sample spreadsheet. Thank you so much in advance.

sample spreadsheet here. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_AjuNfCdGfEM-XkqPa6W4hSIxQg4NM2Vg4c2C1pQ_vQ/edit?usp=sharing

screenshot here. (wont let me post i have no reputation) [image: spreadsheet view]

Comment: You know that in row 16, you also have "delctchy" as "reported"? Is it possible that's throwing you off?

Comment: If you upload an image of the spreadsheet instead of the spreadsheet itself, more people will likely take a look at it. Even a link to an image sharing site such as imgur.com would work.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, the site wont let me upload images. Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: Hi @DaveRGP, the one in Row 16 is delctchy and reported while the value being looked up is delctchy and unreported therefore it should return the column C value in Row 52. Thank you...

Comment: Also, welcome to SO, please see this guide on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and if my answer works, remember to 'accept' it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a `index(match())`? If I've understood correctly you need to match across both the A and B column in sheet one, checking for the relevant values in B and C on sheet 2 to retrun worksheet 2 column a to worksheet 1 column c.

**third version** try:

> =INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$360,MATCH(Sheet1!A1&Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$360&Sheet2!$C$1:$C$360,0))

Basically what this does is use concatenation, the `&` operator, to specify you are looking for "Criteria A" & "Criteria B" in sheet 1, which makes the string "Criteria A Criteria B", which is supplied in the first part of the match function. 
In the second it then says match this against all of my variables in sheet 2 in the same way with concantenation. 
The final part of match function (0) specifies you want an 'exact' match

It then supplied this as a reference to the index function, which then finds the row intersecting with the value you want, and returns that.

As noted here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/59482 this is an array formula, so it behaves differently, and must be input differently. https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

Comment: A simple Index/Match combo won't work here as there are 2 variables being checked against.

Comment: two variable is very possible, as is documented here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/59482

Comment: @VeeEss, you may have to fiddle the exact references here. I've basically done it through logic, but haven't actually implemented it in your sheet. Make sure you understand the `!` to indicate a different sheet and the `$` to make sure the formula doesn't mutate in certain places as you copy down.

Comment: thank you @DaveRGP, i corrected the range value and i get a #VALUE! error.

Comment: Firstly, I realise I made a mistake in operating from memory on how to refer to sheets, secondly, please update the question with the version of excel you're using :)

Comment: @VeeEss Just got it, realised the second argument of match was referring to a and b not b and c as it should have, Third update should work.

Comment: Agreed that using Concatenate with Index / Match will work. However note that you will need to use it as an Array Function - see my answer for details.

Comment: The concatenate idea is brilliant! The formula is not working for me as it is returning a #VALUE! error but the concatenate idea, i can work on that! thank you so much.

Comment: make sure you're entering it as an **array** formula. On Windows thats putting the cursor at the end of the formula and pressing ctrl + shift + enter. Have a look at the link at the bottom I editted in.

Answer (score 1):

In Sheet2, insert a column in front of Column A and put the formula in A2 `=C2&D2`.
Then in Sheet1, Cell C2 the formula `=vlookup(A2&B2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)`.

the first make a concatenated key to lookup, then the second looks up that key.

Comment: @VeeEss Honestly this is probably your best approach as it is simplest. Helper columns are the way to go if you are unfamiliar with Array Formulas / VBA.

Comment: Yup. However, remember that vlookup isn't robust. If your column organisation changes, this will break, hence my preference for `index(match())`

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon this actually worked. i am not familiar with arrays YET. i was looking for something 'automated' but it seems too complicated to execute. its frustrating when you have the idea of what you want to do but cant put it into code. thank you for all your help.

Comment: @DaveRGP thank you too. i just really need a quick solution at the moment because i need to submit this project... thank you for the ideas.

Comment: @VeeEss Honestly for workplace projects using helper columns like this is far simpler to explain / review, and using Array formulas has a lot of drawbacks, like if someone edits your formula and presses TAB/ENTER, it will erase the 'Array' impact. As Dave mentions you can replace this with Index/Match, by saying =INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(C2&D2,Sheet2!A:A,0))

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) 2 ways you could do this without VBA.

**USING A SORTED LIST**

The first relies on the assumption that your data can be re-sorted, so that everything "Unreported" is in the top, and everything "reported" is together below that (or vice versa). Assuming that this is the case (and it appears to already be sorted like this),we will use the function OFFSET to create a new range which shows only the values that align with either being "Unreported" or "Reported".

Offset takes a given reference to a point on a sheet, and then moves down/up & left/right to see what reference you want to return. Then, it returns a range of cells of a given height, and a given width. Here, we will want to start on Sheet2 at the top left, moving down until we find the term "Unreported" or "Reported". Once that term is found, we will want to move one column to the right (to pull column B from sheet 2), and then have a 'height' of as many rows as there are "unreported" or "reported" cells. This will look as follows in A1 on sheet 1, copied down:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)-1,1,COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,A1),1)
```

This says: First, start at cell A1 on sheet2. Then find the term in A1 (either "unreported" or "reported", on sheet2!A:A (we subtract 1 because OFFSET starts at A1 - so if your data starts at A1 we need to actually stay at "0". If you have headers on sheet2, you will not need this -1). Then, move 1 column to the right. Go down the rows for as many times as Sheet2 column A has the term found in Sheet1 A1. Stay 1 column wide. Together, this will leave you with a single range on sheet2, showing column B for the entire length that column A matches your term in sheet1 A1.

Now we need to take that OFFSET, and use it to find out when the term in Sheet1 B1 is matched in Sheet2 column B. This will work as follows:

```
=MATCH(B1,[FORMULA ABOVE],0)
```

This shows the number of rows down, starting at the special OFFSET array created above, that the term from B1 is matched in column B from sheet2. To use this information to pull the result from column C on sheet 2, we can use the INDEX function, like so:

```
=INDEX([FORMULA ABOVE],MATCH(B1,[FORMULA ABOVE],0))
```

Because this would be fairly convoluted to have in a single cell, we can simplify this by using VLOOKUP, which will only require the OFFSET function to be entered a single time. This will work as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,[FORMULA ABOVE],2,0)
```

This takes the OFFSET formula above, finds the matching term in B1, and moves to the 2nd column to get the value from column C in sheet2. Because we are going to use VLOOKUP, the offset formula above will need to be adjusted to provide 2 columns of data instead of 1. Together, this will look as follows:

**FINAL FORMULA FOR SHEET1, C1 & COPIED DOWN**

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)-1,1,COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,A1),2),2,0)
```

**OPTION USING ARRAY FORMULAS**

The above method will only work if your data is sorted so that the REPORTED and UNREPORTED rows are grouped together. If they cannot be sorted, you can use an ARRAY FORMULA, which essentially takes a formula which would normal apply to a single cell, and runs it over an entire range of cells. It returns an array of results, which must be reduced down to a single value. A basic array formula looks like this [assume for this example that A1 = 1, A2 = 2...A5 = 5]:

```
=IF(A1:A5>3,A1:A5,"")
```

Confirm this (and all array functions) by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, instead of just ENTER. This looks at each cell from A1:A5, and if the value is bigger than 3, it gives the number from that cell - otherwise, it returns "". In this case, the result would be the array {"";"";"";4;5}. To get the single total of 9, wrap that in a SUM function:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A5>3,A1:A5,""))
```

In your case, we will want to use an array formula to see what row in Sheet2 matches A1 from Sheet1, and B1 from Sheet1. This will look like this:

```
=IF(Sheet2!$A$1:A$100=A1,IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$100,ROW($B$1:$B$100),""),"")
```

This checks which rows in column A from sheet 2 match A1. For those that do, it then checks which rows in column B from sheet 2 match B1. For those, it pulls the row number from that match. Everything else returns "". Assuming no duplicates, there should only 1 row number which gets returned. To pull that number from the array of results, wrap the whole thing in a MATCH function. Now that you have the row number, you can use an INDEX function to pull the result in Column C with that row, like this:

**FINAL ARRAY FORMULA METHOD**

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$100,MAX(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:A$100=A1,IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$100,ROW(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$100),""),"")))
```

Remember to confirm with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER, when you type this formula. Note that I didn't refer to all of Sheet2!A:A, because array formulas run very slowly over large ranges.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula should work without making any changes to the datasheets.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$360,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,IF(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$360=Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$360),0))
```

Remember to save this formula as an array with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Documentation on how to use `INDEX` and `MATCH` against multiple criteria can be found on [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/59482).

Comment: thanks. i copy and pasted this and it worked! I still dont understand arrays though so if this gets messed up i wont be able to repair it. haha

Comment: Well, array functions typically run over a range instead of over a single cell. What you notice here, is that the IF statement is checking a the range of possibilities to match it against a value.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do with the multiples that do not have corresponding matches. txed is listed as Unreported twice in Sheet1; kntyctap is listed as Unreported three times. There are only one corresponding match on Sheet2 for each of these.

**Non-array Standard Formulas for multiple criteria matches**

For Excel 2010 and above use this standard formula in Sheet1!C1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$999,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(1:999)/((Sheet2!$B$1:$B$999=A2)*(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$999=B1)), COUNTIFS(A$1:A1, A1, B$1:B1, B1))), "")
```

For version of Excel prior to 2010 use this standard formula in Sheet1!C1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$999, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$999)+((Sheet2!$B$1:$B$999<>A1)+(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$999<>B1))*1E+99, , ), COUNTIFS(A$1:A1, A1, B$1:B1, B1))), "")
```

I've handled error with the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) in that latter formula. Excel 2003 and previous may have to use an `IF(ISERROR(..., ...))` combination.